# Tell the difference between buttons in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a quick throw-together website for a little project I'm working on.

I'm using a Modal for users to confirm an action and I'm not sure how to tell the difference between the buttons being pressed within the modal. There is a delete button and a cancel button.

Code:

```js
$('.deleteButton').click((event) => {

                $('#confirmDeleteSingleInfractionModal').modal('toggle');

                let data = {
                    infractionID: $(event.target).attr('referencedInfraction'),
                    targetUserID: $(event.target).attr('targetUserID')
                }


                console.log(data);


                $('#confirmDeleteSingleInfractionModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (close) {

                    
                    if ($(close.relatedTarget).hasClass('cancelButton'))
                        return;



                    console.log('deleting');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'delete',
                        url: `${window.location.origin}/dataLink/infraction`,
                        data,
                        success: () => {

                        },
                        error: () => {
                            showInfractionDeleteError();
                        }
                    })

                })
            });
```

I gave all the cancel buttons a `cancelButton` class so I could use jQuery to check if it was a cancel button.

However, I've come to notice that it still doesn't return even if it has the class (the button code is below)

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                    </svg> Delete </button>
                <button type="button" class="cancelButton btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
```

If anybody has any suggestions as to how I could make it return when the button pressed has the `cancelButton` class or any other way to do what I'm trying to do, that would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On `hide.bs.modal`, the event provided in `function (close) {` is not the same as the one in `$('.deleteButton').click((event) => {`.

In your code, every time the `.deleteButton` is clicked, the modal display is toggled... And a new `hide.bs.modal` event listener is registered (not executed right away)... But milliseconds after, the modal toggling fires the `hide.bs.modal`... Making you think it is directly related to the `.deleteButton` click... Which is wrong.

That can be confusing, I agree.

Just assume that registering an event handler inside another event handler is wrong 99% of the time.

What is inside the `hide.bs.modal` event handler execute every time the modal closes. Whatever the close reason. If you console.log `close.relatedTarget`... You would notice it isn't a reference to the `.deleteButton` button. It probably is squarely `undefined` (I did not check).

So here is my suggestion:

```
$('.deleteButton').click((event) => {
    
    // Something to do when a .deleteButton is clicked
    
    $('#confirmDeleteSingleInfractionModal').modal('toggle');

    let data = {
        infractionID: $(event.target).attr('referencedInfraction'),
        targetUserID: $(event.target).attr('targetUserID')
    }

    console.log(data);
    console.log('deleting');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'delete',
        url: `${window.location.origin}/dataLink/infraction`,
        data,
        success: () => {

        },
        error: () => {
            showInfractionDeleteError();
        }
    })
});

$('.cancelButton').click((event) => {

  // Something to do when a .cancelButton is clicked
  // ...
})

$('#confirmDeleteSingleInfractionModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (close) {

  // Something else to do on modal close (Whatever the close reason)
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the

```
$('#confirmDeleteSingleInfractionModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (close) {...}
```

is nested inside the

```
$('.deleteButton').click((event) {...}
```

so i would take it out of there.

Second, provide two different event handlers for the two different buttons (cancel and delete) and handle the action you wish in each event handler.
In order to tell the difference between the buttons being pressed within the modal you can provide two different classes for each button. let's apply "cancel-button" class for the cancel button and "delete-button" for the delete button.

```
$('.cancel-button').click((event) => {
     // cancel action
})

$('.delete-button').click((event) => {
     // delete action
})
```

Comment: I was going to separate them, but I need to be able to get a custom attribute found in the `deleteButton`. If I move the actual Ajax code to the confirm button on the Modal, I won't be able to access the custom attribute of the original button pressed.